# create page to edit PDF using JavaScript in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

How i can create  a PDF.js Annotations in oracle apex , it's possible or not please any advise ?

Comment: Have you tried googling "javascript annotate pdf"? I saw a few hits, some free (though maybe not maintained anymore) and others paid.

Comment: See this too (it works in browsers too): http://thecodebarbarian.com/working-with-pdfs-in-node-js.html

Comment: Thanks dan i will try that , i want add signature in any position specified by user (dynamic position).

Comment: Dear dan , i want  ask you another question,  i want to call web service and this web service have authentication user and password,  how i can call this web service and  save data in table , and schedule to call this  web service hourly.

Comment: Above by plsql code

Comment: Hi Jaw, you should ask another question in SO for that. That will give many people the opportunity to answer, rather than just me.